# warning C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow

Tags: c++

I encountered a strange thing when I was programming under [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). It's about a `32bit` Addition for `signed` numbers

```
(uint32)(SIN32_MIN * (-1)) //signed integer 4 bytes
```

gives :

```
warning C4307: '*' : integral constant overflow
```

with `SIN32_MIN` = `-2147483648`.

Comment: `signed numbers` and `(uint32)`......o.O

Comment: SIN32_MIN = -2147483648

Comment: undefined behaviour

Answer (score 4):

If you multiply `INT32_MIN`  by `-1` you'll get overflow since 2147483648 cannot be represented by a signed 32-bit integer.

If you are trying to get -1 * (-2147483648) = `2147483648`, then try doing this instead: `(((uint32_t)(INT32_MAX)) + 1)`

[Sample code](https://ideone.com/QMGpoc):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t n = static_cast<uint32_t>(INT32_MAX)+1;
    printf("n: %u\n", n);
}
```

Output:

```
n: 2147483648
```

This produces [no warnings with clang](https://godbolt.org/g/yocKyJ).

As a side node, usually INT32_MIN isn't defined as `#define INT32_MIN -2147483648` for similar reasons. It's usually defined as `(-2147483647 - 1)` or something like that.

You may also [do this instead](https://ideone.com/FzmD7B): `(uint32_t)(INT32_MIN * -1LL)`

Comment: (((uint32_t)(INT32_MAX)) + 1); SAME ERROR COMPILER THROWING

Comment: @user3231318 Are you sure? Did you check [sample code](https://ideone.com/l9K4vP)?

Comment: @Pavel Actually IDEOne doesn't raise a warning even with an overflow. https://ideone.com/VMAVB2

Answer (score 3):

In an environment where integers are [2's complement](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) (which is almost any modern general purpose computer) the range of numbers that can be represented in a fixed number of bits is not symmetric about 0. In a 32 bit number, the biggest positive number that can be represented is 2147483647 which is in binary

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

The number -2147483648 * -1 is 2147483648 which is the same as 2147483647 + 1, but when we add 1 to this, the bit pattern is

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The top bit is set, which means it is the representation of a negative number. In fact it is -2147483648. +2147483648 is not representable in 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Formula `SIN32_MIN * (-1)` result is `2147483648` which is out of `signed int32` range:

```
–2147483648 to 2147483647
```